# Confused about the sense of GDI at all

Tags: c++, winapi, graphics, gdi

I was starting to learn Windows programing few years ago, and I always used only "native" environment for my needs. I mean, I write code only using Winapi, not DirectX\Draw\2D\etc for graphics, not any external libraries for music or something else, just only Winapi. I'm working on the next evolution step of my graphical render due last time. Previouly algorithms were good, they redraws only parts of windows that should to be redraw, and it works for *not fullscreened* windows. But when I worked with full-screen cases, I've got very small fps.

So, few monthes ago, I've understood, that I can make a brand new algorithm: instead of make draws in `WM_PAINT`, every time recreate dc'c, bitmaps, I can run a parallel thread, where in eternal loop goes redrawing, dc'c and bitmaps creates only one time + I even can don't use Gdi or Gdi+ functions such as `Rectangle`, `Graphics::FillRect`, but write my own faster functions. So I did it. And what I've got:

62 fps, 1920\1080 **with no any graphical load**

**why?**

It's just this code

```
void render()
{
COLORREF *matrix;

matrix = re->GetMatrix();

while (1)
{
    Sleep(1000 / 120);

    re->Render();

    //below goes fps counter, that counts in another thread
    while (!mu.try_lock())
    {

    }

    frames++;
    mu.unlock();
}
}
```

re->Render function

```
inline void Card::Render()
{
//SetDIBits(hdcc, bm, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, matrix, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
//StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdcc, 0, 0, width, height, SRCCOPY);
//method above with Stretch or just BitBlt is awfull at all

SetDIBitsToDevice(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0, 0, bi.bmiHeader.biHeight, matrix, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);//hdc is a surface dc, not memory
}
```

So if I understanding well, it is the maximum, that can be taken from Gdi. If I right, the question is - **what is the sense of Gdi?** Computer games were developed on Direct 2D then DirectX\OpenGL, user interfaces, before NT 8 were *not* window less, and(or) used DirectDraw. I'm confused, is it really to write good software render do not using any library, just by yourself?

Comment: GDI is for applications, not games.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, hah, no I just want to create something by myself. And I've noticed, that many people were encountered this problem too

Comment: @Anders, I thought it for graphics..

Comment: GDI has roots in the days of the 286 CPU. It's for writing to pretty much any graphics device from the screen to the printer. It's going to do some really, really questionable things with respect to modern high-speed graphics because that's not what it was designed to do.

Comment: Are you asking if GDI is designed for full screen gaming?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yeah I'm asking, is it possible to develop full screen apps only with Gdi

Comment: There is no need to recreate bitmaps and brushes on every `WM_PAINT`. Also it is not clear where exactly does that background thread get its GDI objects from. There are no checks of whether GDI calls succeeded. Also note that multithreaded access to GDI resources is not serialized so you may get into race condition.

Comment: Why do you think MS developed DirectX?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I don't understand why they developed Gdi

Comment: They wanted something that could write to many different types of device (screens, different types of printers, plotters, etc). And they didn't have today's technologies.

Comment: Are you trolling? Surely you know that GDI came before DirectX/opengl

Comment: GDI was just the first graphics library that Microsoft created for Windows.  Goes back to 1987 and Windows version 2.  DirectX was released in 1995, its aim was to get game authors to switch from DOS and avoid OpenGL's beefy requirements.  Also the time that video hardware was evolving very rapidly.

Comment: Now is the time to take the [tour]. Also read [ask], to understand, why this question was ill-received, and closed.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is here:

```
Sleep(1000 / 120);
```

comes out to 8 ms (after integer division).  But Sleep is not a very precise timing mechanism.  It will sleep for *at least* the amount of time specified.  And, with the default clock tick rate, it will sleep for at least 15.6 ms on most configurations.  A frame duration of 15.6 ms is very close to 62 frames per second, so that's probably the root problem.

Beyond that, you will have problems with GDI because the graphics operations are largely performed in system memory which then has to be transferred to graphics memory.  At higher resolutions, it can be difficult to do this at a high frame rate, depending on the hardware in use.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I understand your question but here’s my best guess.

> I can run a parallel thread

Not a good idea for GDI. WinAPI can go multithreading, but it’s tricky to use correctly, see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810439.aspx

> 62 fps, 1920\1080 with no any graphical load. why?

GDI wasn’t designed for the high-FPS use case you want from that. It was designed to redraw stuff when something changed. It was designed before modern GPUs.

On modern hardware, the way to get high FPS and/or low latency rendering is by using GPU-centric technologies. In C++, that’s Direct3D and Direct2D.

> is it really to write good software render do not using any library

Sure it’s possible. Just not the way you’re trying to do it with SetDIBitsToDevice.

On modern hardware + OS, your API calls (regardless on what the API is) will become commands sent to 3D GPU. That’s why newer GPU-centric APIs like D3D and D2D often deliver better performance.

If you want to implement a software render that’s fine, just keep in mind you have to upload the result to a GPU texture. On modern Windows, WinAPI does just that under the hood.

Legacy Windows (i.e. anything before Vista) didn’t rely on GPU for that. But games didn’t use GDI either, they used DirectX 9, DirectDraw, etc…